# Getting third level ul to toggle respective UL on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently working with a few uls and trying to find out how to get the third level to open and if another third level ul link is clicked then that ul closes and the clicked one opens. I have a wroking code for the second level UL's just the third is confucing as I am still in the learning stages of jquery. Here is my code:

```
<ul>
         <li>
                    <a href="#" class="button">Humanities</a>
                    <ul class="subul">            
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="button-2">Literature</a>
                            <ul class="subsubul">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Academic Writing</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">American Literature</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Biography</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Classics</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Comedy</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Drama</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">European Literature</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Fiction</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Nonfiction Prose</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Poetry</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Technical Writing</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Tragedy</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">World Literature</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                
                        <li>
                            <a href="{mylink-here}"">Philosophy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="button-2">Religion</a>
                            <ul class="subsubul">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Buddhism</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Christianity</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Hinduism</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Islam</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Judaism</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">Theology</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="button">Language</a>
                    <ul class="subul">            
                        <li>
                            <a href="{mylink-here}">Linguistics</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
     </li>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("ul.subsubul").hide().addClass("subclosed");
        $("a.button-2").each(function() {   
            $(this).click(function() {
                var index = $(this).parent().index();
                $('.subclosed').hide();
                $('.subclosed').eq(index).slideToggle("slow");
            });    
        }); 
        $("ul.subul").hide().addClass("closed");               
        $("a.button").each(function() {   
            $(this).click(function() {
                var index = $(this).parent().index();
                $('.closed').hide();
                $('.closed').eq(index).slideToggle("slow");
            });    
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Thre masy be a few sytax errors in the HTML as I have dumbed down the massive list I am working with but this is the basics of it. I got the jQuery to a point where is will open and close the third level but opens the same 3rd level ul for each link. Im really confused as of now. Any help is much appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to build an accordion.
Use [jquery ui's accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) widget, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you;)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
  <meta name="author" content=""/>
  <meta name="description" content=""/>
  <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  *{margin:0;padding:0;}

  .wrapper{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;      
  margin:0px auto;
  margin-top:40px;
  background-color:black;
  position:relative;
  }

 .wrapper ul
 {
 list-style-type:none;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

 .wrapper ul li ul a{line-height:20px;}

 .active{
 clear:both;
 padding-bottom:3px;
 }

 a{
 color:white;
 display:block;
 width:100px;
 text-decoration:none;
 height:20px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:20px;
 }

 .service{
 background-color:red;
 display:block;
 width:100px;
 text-decoration:none;
 height:20px;
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
 outline:none;
 }

 .about{
 background-color:red;
 display:block;
 width:100px;
 text-decoration:none;
 height:20px;
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
 outline:none;
 }

 .home{
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  text-decoration:none;
  height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
  outline:none;
  }

 .contact{
 background-color:red;
 display:block;
 width:100px;
 text-decoration:none;
 height:20px;
 text-align:center;
 border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
 outline:none;
 }

 </style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.wrapper ul li ul:first').addClass('active');
$('.wrapper ul li ul').hide();  
$('.wrapper ul li a:not(.wrapper ul li ul li a)').click(function(){
 if($('.wrapper ul li a').next('ul').hasClass('active')){         
  $('.active').slideUp('slow');
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).next('ul').addClass('active');
  $('.active:not(:animated)').slideDown('slow');
  }
  /*if user clicks like crazy sometimes our active class
      disapears altogether... code below will FIX that :) */ 
 else if($('.active').length===0){   
  $(this).next('ul').addClass('active');
  $('.active:not(:animated)').slideDown('slow');
  }

     });
     });


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

 <div class="wrapper">
 <ul>
 <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
 </ul>

 </li>


 <li><a class="about" href="#">About Us</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a class="service" href="#">Service</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
 </ul>

 </li>

 <li><a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
```